# What's the difference between portal and newly introduced salesforce community

Tags: salesforce, portal

After introduction with salesforce community, I am unable to clear how community is different from portal functionality. I already read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14539/how-are-sites-partner-portal-customer-portal-and-communities-different-from-ea) but this don't have answers of question like:

- What is new things being provided by community?
- What are restriction we have if we use community?
- Advantage of community over portal.
- Is it capable of provide Email functionalities as same we have in other organization types?
- Role of chatter in communities etc.
- Is their difference between portal user and community user?

I already know that community is dedicated feature for portal functionality, but is it have some new functionality or only a portal part is separated?

Please provide some summary, links or answers you have.

Answer (score 1):

While there are probably more detailed answers, it sounds like you are looking for a high-level overview.  Communities basically combines Partner Portal, Customer Portal and chatter capabilities (so users can chatter on records they have access to, etc.)

Security, sharing, etc. are basically the same.  There are standard responses on how it makes things more social and provides a path to greater communication but I think it comes down to combining the portals + chatter.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that you will have more flexibility in terms of branding, integrating the communities with site.com CMS for publishing pages and also above all full Chatter integration for all things social.

The old Customer portal and Partner portals had an outdated look and feel and very basic support for publishing a full blown portal. The old Customer and Partner portals are retired and no longer offered, so your only option is not Communities.

With Salesforce 1 platform, now you can have a fully mobile optimized community portals as well.

You can also consider another solution called [Magentrix](http://www.magentrix.com) which fully integrates with Salesforce CRM and allows you to build branded self-service mobile portals and more.